# Python File I/O operations leads to “[Errno 23] Too many open files in system”

Tags: python, file-io, xml-parsing, file-handling

I am trying to iteratively process a list of compressed files. Each compressed file contains a large number of XML documents, some even contain up to 92,000 XML documents. Inside the nested loop, I am iterating over the list of extracted XML documents and pulling specific XML field values from each XML document. The problem is that I keep running into following issue after 5 minutes of the script running: **[Errno 23] Too many open files in system**.

When I uncomment the call to ‘*parse_xml_files*’ from the main function below, the script goes to completion without any issues.  I am confused what is causing this issue since the files are being read using a context manager which should by itself close each XML files after they have been processed. May be I am overlooking something.

Many solutions on stackoverflow seems to be revolving around permanently increasing the limit of number of open files using ‘ulimit -a’. However, this solution does not work for me as I am dealing with such as a large number of files.

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated!

```
from os import system
from os import walk, path as ospath, makedirs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import walk


def find_all_xml_files(path):
    file_queue = []
    for (dirpath, _, filenames) in walk(path):
        if len(filenames) == 0:
            continue
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.xml'):
                file_queue.append(f'{dirpath}/{filename}')
            else:
                # Ignore unknown file formats
                pass 
    return file_queue


def parse_xml_files(xml_files):
    for xml_file in xml_files:
        with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
            handler = f.read()
        xml_doc = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')
        """ And then extract and store various parts of the XML document """


def main():
    # Retrieve list of files to process
    compressed_files = get_files_to_process()

    for compressed_file in compressed_files:
         temp_folder = f'.temp'  # Temporary directory to store extracted contents

         # Create temporary storage file
         makedirs(temp_folder)

         # Unzip the compressed file
         unzip_cmd = f'unzip -o {compressed_file} -d {temp_folder}'
         system(unzip_cmd)

         # Retrieve list of extracted XML files for parsing
         xml_files = find_all_xml_files(temp_folder)
         parse_xml_files(xml_files)  # Commenting this line helps the script go to completion without any errors

         # Delete temporary direcory and its content
         delete_cmd = f'rm -r {temp_folder}'
         system(delete_cmd)

main()
```

**Update**:

This is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 30, in main
  File "main.py", line 8, in main
  OSError: [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '.temp/xyz.xml'
```

After the above traceback is shown, I am having to reboot my entire system because everything running on my laptop becomes unresponsive.

Comment: shouldn't this `with open(filename, 'r') as f:`  use `xml_file` instead of `filename`?

Comment: Yes. That's an edit mistake. When I wrote this post I wanted to give meaningful variable names but forgot about that variable. Thanks.

Comment: You could try to add a `return` after `handler = f.read()` to find out if really the files opened by you are the problem or something done by Beautifulsoup or the following code. The other way around would be to only open one file once, read `handler` data and feed it to your XML processing over and over again.

Comment: The problem has to be in the `""" And then extract and store various parts of the XML document """` part that you didn't show us.

Comment: Move `xml_doc = BeautifulSoup(...` outside the `with open(...` blocks, as variable `handler` holds the XML content.

Comment: Thanks guys the rapid response!

@MichaelButscher - I did that and the issue still persisted. This means that this is definitely caused by the file handling. The error traceback points to `with open(xml_file, 'r') as f` inside the `parse_xml_files` function. And, yes I am only reading the file *once*, and feeding it to my XML processing multiple times.

Comment: @JohnGordon - At the moment, everything below `xml_doc = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')` in the `parse_xml_files` function has been commented out. So, I know the problem isn’t caused by those parts.

Comment: @stovfl - You make a good point. Initially within the context manager I only had `handler = f.read()`. But during error debugging I moved everything inside the context manager to see if it would make any difference. It did not. (I updated code).

Comment: In the part of `parse_xml_files()` that you haven't shown us, are you calling `main()`?  That would create infinite recursion, which would explain the error.

Comment: No. I am afraid I am calling `main()` just the one time. I have just included the `find_all_xml_files ` function which does a depth-first search in the extracted folder. Can you see anything wrong with that?